# Counting vectors of natual number with restrictions on coordinates

Tags: combinatorics, vectors

I have to count some vectors $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{N}^n_{\geq0}$. Futhermore thier coordinates should fullfill:

$$0=\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\cdots=\lambda_{k-1}=\lambda_k<\lambda_{k+1}<\cdots <\lambda_{n-1}<\lambda_{n}\leq n$$

for $k=1,\ldots,n$. My paper says that there are $2^{n}$ of them (might be wrong, already found some other mistakes in there) but I have no clue how the autor worked that out. I would be really gratefull if one of you could help me out with that.

Comment: Can you describe your requirements a little more carefully?  Are you trying to get at something like: sequences of length $n$ which start with some (nonzero?  positive?) number of zeroes, followed by a strictly increasing sequence bounded above (strictly) by $n$?

Comment: @NickPeterson The index where the $\lambda$'s start beeing $>0$ corresponds to $1\leq k\leq n$. So yes, like you described (just the upper bound is not strict - my mistake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a recurrence.  Define $N(p,n)$ as the number of strictly increasing sequences of length $p$ with maximum term no more than $n$ and minimum term at least $1$.  $p$ here corresponds to $n-k+1$ in your question.  The recurrence is $N(p,n)=N(p-1,n-1)+N(p-1,n-1)$ where the first term covers the sequences that end in $n$ and the second term covers those that do not end in $n$.  The boundary conditions are that $N(k,k)=1$ as you must have the sequence from $1$ to $k$ and $N(0,n)=1$ as there is one empty sequence.  The number of acceptable sequences of length $n$ is then $\sum_{i=0}^nN(i,n)$ because we can pad the ones shorter than $n$ with any number of zeros.  It turns out $N(p,n)={n \choose p}$-this is Pascal's triangle.  The sum just sums the entries in row $n$ in Pascal's triangle, which is known to sum to $2^n$

Comment: Ok. Assume after the 2nd and the 4th is a bar. The corresponding $\lambda$'s would be $\lambda_0=\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$, $\lambda_3=\lambda_4=1$, $\lambda_5=2$. Like you said it is a valid tuple but it violates my stated condition.

Comment: I have replaced it entirely.

Comment: Ok looks good. But in the recurrence souldn't the first term be $N(p-1,n)$? Which would correspond to the explanation/definition.

Comment: @zivimo:  yes, that was a typo.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

My argument is the follwoing. If we fix some $k$, and $\lambda_{n}= n-k$, then  $\#(vectors) =1$. If we have $\lambda_{n} = n-k+1$, than we can have only one "missed" value, that is we will have $\#(vectors) =n-k+1$. For the next we will have, that if $\lambda_{n} = n-k+2$, than we will have to missing values. So $\binom{n-k+2}{2}$. And for the fixed $k$, we will have $\#(vectors) = 1+\binom{n-k+1}{1} + ... + \binom{n}{k}$.
And for all $k$-s starting from $k=2$(as for sure $\lambda_{1}=0$, as you have written), we will have  $$\#(vectors) = \sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n-k+i}{i}$$

Comment: If $k=2 \Rightarrow \lambda_2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1=0$ so the last sentence is is not true.

Comment: Yes. That's was just a mistake. I edited.